# Runtime Error: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: objective-c, ios7

i have the following error, when i run xcode5, i am using parse.com as my backend and i am using parse.com login api, but i have the following error, i don't know whats happening.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:  
 '[<LoginViewController 0x99b8580> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key     
 value coding-compliant for the key password.'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

please help me figure this out.thanks

Comment: Did you set the key "password" ?

Comment: Is this error only occuring on xcode5?

Comment: Check your outlets.  Also, check SO before asking this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key.  66 pages of questions with the same title should give you an answer somewhere.

Comment: @ connor am currently using xcode5, i don't know about the others,@ Shivan Raptor what do u mean by set the key password?

Comment: It looks like a property `password` was attempted to be set on a class that does not have such a property.

Comment: yes it seems so, but i have redone everything from scratch, still got the same problem,

Comment: Check custom runtime keypaths as well.  It's entirely possible you added one and forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your situation but deleting the outlet connection and reconnecting them did work for me like a charm

[image]